# Duplicate Email with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I am a beginner with ruby on rails. I am trying to test duplicate email scenario with rspec and capybara gems.

Here is my user test spec:

```
    require 'rails_helper'

feature "User signs up", type: :feature do
  # before do
  #   click_link "Sign up"
  #   expect(current_path).to eq(new_user_registration_path)
  #   fill_in "Name", with: "Test"
  #   fill_in "Surname", with: "Test"
  #   fill_in "Email", with: "tester@example.tld"
  #   fill_in "Password", with: "test-password"
  #   fill_in "Password confirmation", with: "test-password"
  #   click_button "Sign up"
  # end

  scenario "successfully" do
    visit "/"

    click_link "Sign up"
    expect(current_path).to eq(new_user_registration_path)
    fill_in "Name", with: "Test"
    fill_in "Surname", with: "Test"
    fill_in "Email", with: "tester@example.tld"
    fill_in "Password", with: "test-password"
    fill_in "Password confirmation", with: "test-password"
    click_button "Sign up"

    expect(current_path).to eq "/"
    expect(page).to have_content(
      "A message with a confirmation link has been sent to your email address.
      Please follow the link to activate your account."
    )

    open_email "tester@example.tld", with_subject: "Confirmation instructions"
    visit_in_email "Confirm my account"

    expect(current_path).to eq new_user_session_path
    expect(page).to have_content "Your email address has been successfully confirmed."

    fill_in "Email", with: "tester@example.tld"
    fill_in "Password", with: "test-password"
    click_button "Log in"

    expect(current_path).to eq "/"
    expect(page).to have_content "Signed in successfully."
    expect(page).to have_content "Hello Test"


  end

  scenario "usuccessfully - Invalid email " do
    visit "/"

    click_link  "Sign up"
    expect(current_path).to eq(new_user_registration_path)
    fill_in "Name", with: "Test"
    fill_in "Surname", with: "Test"
    fill_in "Email", with: "invalid-email"
    fill_in "Password", with: "test-password"
    fill_in "Password confirmation", with: "test-password"
    click_button "Sign up"
    expect(current_path).to eq "/users"
    expect(page).to have_content(
      "Email is invalid"
        )
  end
  scenario "usuccessfully - Duplicate email " do
    visit "/"

    click_link "Sign up"
    expect(current_path).to eq(new_user_registration_path)
    fill_in "Name", with: "Test"
    fill_in "Surname", with: "Test"
    fill_in "Email", with: "tester@example.tld"
    fill_in "Password", with: "test-password"
    fill_in "Password confirmation", with: "test-password"
    click_button "Sign up"
    expect(current_path).to eq "/users"
    expect(page).to have_content(
      "Email has already been taken"
        )
  end

end

feature "User signing", type: :feature do
  scenario "usuccessfully" do
    visit "/"

    click_link "Sign in"
    expect(current_path).to eq(new_user_session_path)
    fill_in "Email", with: "wrong-email@example.tld"
    fill_in "Password", with: "wrong-password"
    click_button "Log in"

    expect(current_path).to eq(new_user_session_path)
    expect(page).to have_content(
      "Invalid email or password."
    )

    # expect(current_path).to eq new_user_session_path
    # expect(page).to have_content "Your email address has been successfully confirmed."

    # fill_in "Email", with: "tester@example.tld"
    # fill_in "Password", with: "test-password"
    # click_button "Log in"

    # expect(current_path).to eq "/"
    # expect(page).to have_content "Signed in successfully."
    # expect(page).to have_content "Hello Zein"


  end
end
```

I am receiving the following failure:

```
  1) User signs up usuccessfully - Duplicate email 
     Failure/Error: expect(current_path).to eq "/users"

       expected: "/users"
            got: "/"

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/features/user_sign_ups_spec.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How do I create a duplicate user with capybara gem ?
Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Factory Girl gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails) (if you're not using it already). Let's start with a simple `user` factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "person#{n}@example.com" }
    first_name 'Tyrion'
    last_name 'Lannister'
    password 'test1234'
  end
end
```

Then you can construct a test where a user with a given email already exists - simply create one in the `before` block that is executed before the test itself:

```
context 'email is already taken' do
  before do
    create(:user, email: 'taken@gmail.com')
  end
  it 'notifies the user about a duplicate email' do
    # visit your page
    fill_in 'Email', with: 'taken@gmail.com'
    # fill in the rest of the fields
    click_button 'Sign up'
    expect(page).to have_content 'Email has already been taken'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is close. What you should do is create a `User` (which you can do using FactoryBot like someone else already suggested, or just create one inside the test like `User.create!`...), then try to register a user using the same info with your "fill-in" methods.